# Powershell script appears to be stuck in else statement and never executes switch

Tags: security, powershell, service, path

The following Powershell script was wrote to scan and fix unquoted service paths containing white space within the referenced path susceptible to exploitation. The script, when ran ".\Get-ServicePathVulnerabilities" with any of the permitted switches, never executes the if statement for the $Fix (-Fix) switch. Please, review this source code and help me identify the issue, as this is a very convenient script to have in anyone's arsenal.

```
Function Get-ServicePathVulnerabilities {
[Cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [switch]$Fix
) # End Param


Begin {
    $VulnerableServices=@()

    if ($Fix){Write-Verbose "Scan Mode: Fix"} else {Write-Verbose "Scan Mode: Audit"}

} # End Begin


Process {

    # Gather Services information from WMI
    $Services = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -Property name,pathname

    # Filter out services that have been enclosed with quotations
    $UnquotedPath = $Services | Where-Object {$_.PathName -notmatch '"'} | Select Name,PathName

    # Loop through services without quotations
    foreach ($Path in $UnquotedPath) {

        $Drive = $Path.PathName | Split-Path -Qualifier
        $Executable = $Path.PathName | Split-Path -Leaf

        # Conditional Logic to determine vulnerability
        # Note: Some service paths may be unquoted and include spaces, but not vulnerable. They could just be a path to executable (no spaces) with a command line switch parameter that may contain a space.
        #       To avoid false positives, the logic below will exclude spaces used in any parameters
        if( ($Path.PathName -match ' ') -and ($Executable -notmatch ' ') -and ($Path.PathName -notmatch './') ) {

            # Vulnerability Found
            Write-Warning ("Unquoted Service Path Discovered for " + $Path.Name + "    PATH: " + $Path.PathName)
            $VulnerableServices += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                ServiceName = $Path.Name
                ServicePath = $Path.PathName
                HostName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            } # End Object

        } # End conditional operators

    } # End Foreach Path in UnquotedPath



    # Attempt to encapsulate path in quotes if specified
    if ($Fix) {
        $VulnerableServices | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Verbose ("Attempting to fix " + $_.Servicename)
            $OriginalPath = $_.ServicePath
            $QuotedServicePath = ('"' + $_.ServicePath + '"')
            $RegistryLocation = ('HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\' + $_.ServiceName)

            Try {
                Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryLocation -Name ImagePath -Value $QuotedServicePath -Verbose
                $_.ServicePath = $QuotedServicePath
            } Catch {
                Write-Error ("Unable to fix " + $_.Servicename)
            } # End Try/Catch


        } # End Foreach object in VulnerableServices

    } # End if Fix was Specified


} # End Process


End {

    if ($VulnerableServices) {Return $VulnerableServices} else {Write-Verbose "No Unquoted Service path Vulnerabilites have been found"}

} # End End

} # Get-ServicePathVulnerabilites
```

Comment: How are you running it **exactly** and what isn't happening exactly?

Comment: I've simply set my execution policy to unrestricted, entered the Powershell cli via an elevated command prompt, and then cd'd into the directory the script is located, then I run the script using .\Get-ServicePathVulnerabilities otherwise Powershell won't allow you to execute it. Though, when I execute the script using the -Fix or -Verbose or both of them, I get the same yellow lettered output as running .\Get-ServicePathVulnerabilities without any switches.

Comment: It works as it should when in Powershell ISE debug cli because you don't have to use .\ but of course from there you can't access the registry when debugging.

Comment: What "same yellow lettered output"? What output are you getting? What output aren't you getting that you expect to be getting?

Comment: This is the output I expect I should be getting, aside from the service entries, as mine will be different. http://i0.wp.com/securekomodo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/ServicePath-Results1.png Instead, I receive only the Audit output, but in yellow and isn't even in the proper format that the Audit output should be printing in. See here, http://oi57.tinypic.com/qqwoqs.jpg

Comment: The color of the text almost certainly doesn't matter as that is almost certainly configurable as part of the profile. Is the name of your script file `Get-ServicePathVulnerabilities`? Because that's also the name of the function in that snippet. Does naming the file something else and then using `. new_file.ps1` and then running `Get-ServicePathVulnerabilities -Fix -Verbose` work?

Comment: It does, if the script executes properly, as shown in the second image in my previous comment. If you execute the script in the ISE debug environment, it does execute properly and outputs the proper format and triggers the proper switch, but of course in the debugging environment your script isn't allowed to access the registry and/or modify it in any way. As for renaming the script and executing it just as you recommended, I have tried this, I've even went as far as placing it in my System32 just like the developer did. That was a smooth recommendation though, also I only see one switch $Fix.

Comment: I don't understand that command about only "one switch $Fix" and what do you get about arguments if you run `help Get-ServicePathVulnerabilities`?